# angular route resolver or onInit?

Tags: angular, typescript

What better for using `resolver` service or get data in OnInit hook? For example, if I need get data from 3 different sources into 1 page better user resolver or write code into ngOnInit?

code

```
ngOnInit() {
  service1.getData().subscribe(c => {
    this.data1 = c;
  });
  service2.getData().subscribe(c => {
    this.data2 = c;
  });
  service3.getData().subscribe(c => {
    this.data3 = c;
  });
}
```

OR

```
RouterModule.forRoot([{
  path: 'page/:id',
  component: blabla,
  resolve: {
    data1: service1,
    data2: service2,
    data3: service3
  }
}])

ngOnInit() {
  this.data1 = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.data.data1;
  this.data2 = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.data.data2;
  this.data3 = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.data.data3;
}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The main difference between `resolvers` and `onInit` is the synchronicity.

- `Resolver` is synchronous.

  - You should use it when you need the data before the component is loaded.
  - You block the component loading.
  - You don't inject the service into the component (you can't use other methods there)
- `OnInit` is asynchronous (in your code).

  - You should use it when there is no need for the data being available before loading the component.
  - You don't block the component loading.
  - You inject the service into the component, therefore you can use other methods from this service.

Take a look at this site: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/10/resolving-route-data-in-angular-2.html

Answer (score 12):

Well it depends. If the component cannot function without the `data1`, `data2`, and `data3`, then the resolve approach makes a lot of sense. An example would be you bank account page. You do not really care about the page until you can see the details of your account.

If you can show something to the user while he awaits for the data it might be better to get the data in the `ngOnInit`. An example would be a product page, where `data{1,2,3}` is a stream of recommended products. The product page can still be shown, even without the recommendations, and the recommended products can continue to load while the user can interact with the rest of the page.

It will be very hard for anyone to answer this question without a deeper understanding of your business logic requirements.

Answer (score 4):

It's important to understand that `route resolvers` and `component ngOnInit` are two different solutions to two different problems, meaning that one tool is not better than the other.

I would say the best practice is to use both in your application, depending on the situation - sometimes it makes sense, UX-wise, to display a view synchronously (blocking until data is loaded) and other times it's better to display the view immediately and load data asynchronously.

So, it's not an application design or architectural decision - It's a UX/UI decision.